# No trusted certificate found for hdfs fsck / command

Tags: java, security, hadoop, ssl, kerberos

I have configured hadoop-2.6.0 secured with kerberos in windows. Everything working fine. But when i execute the below command

```
hdfs fsck /
```

I am getting following exception.

**Exception**

> >
>   Connecting to namenode via https://hostname:50470
>   Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.val
>   idator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
>           at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.
>   java:1341)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.jav
>   a:153)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.
>   java:1312)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339
>   )
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323
>   )
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:
>   563)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect
>   (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLCon
>   nectionImpl.java:153)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticato
>   r.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:186)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.ope
>   nConnection(AuthenticatedURL.java:216)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.URLConnectionFactory.openConnection(URLCon
>   nectionFactory.java:164)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.doWork(DFSck.java:303)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.access$000(DFSck.java:72)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck$1.run(DFSck.java:145)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck$1.run(DFSck.java:142)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
>   tion.java:1628)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.run(DFSck.java:141)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.main(DFSck.java:341)
>   Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate fou
>   nd
>           at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.buildTrustedChain(SimpleValida
>   tor.java:384)
>           at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator
>   .java:134)
>           at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
>           at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.j
>   ava:326)
>           at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerIm
>   pl.java:231)
>           at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustMan
>   agerImpl.java:107)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.ssl.ReloadingX509TrustManager.checkServerT
>   rusted(ReloadingX509TrustManager.java:129)
>           at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLCo
>   ntextImpl.java:813)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.
>   java:1323)
>           ... 24 more

i have exported certificate from my default browser and added into the keystore using below commands but still facing the same error.

```
keytool -import -alias nncert -keystore c:\Java\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file nn.crt
```

Help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is cacerts the default trust store used by your Java process ?

Comment: No. Its C:\Users\Username\.keystore. I imported the certificates into that also. But still the same problem.

Comment: Enable the SSL debug options to get a detailed overview of what is happening. The parameter to pass to the VM is ` -Djavax.net.debug=all`. The [documentation on the debugging is useful too](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html).

Comment: Yes enabled. But i couldn't understand any details from that. Added all trusted certificates from the cacerts but the error still occurs. It seems it need any other certificate?? @DeepakBala

Comment: @Malli simple command only... hdfs fsck /

Comment: The output from the debug should show you which trust store is used and why the certificate validation failed. Update your post with the SSL debug output.

Comment: Yes as you said it added my certificate correctly the following exception thrown.  
  
 %% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 2E                               .......
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
i am getting this exception. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by following the steps from [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-set-up-a-hadoop-cluster-with-network-encryption/) link.

Once certificate is exported, it should add in the default location of java truststore %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts as fsck command use default location for ssl.

Hope this may help to someone.